# SearchView in Toolbar background same as toolbar

Tags: android, background, searchview

I'm adding a SearchView within a Toolbar of the app. When activated, the search input text's background is semi-transparent white. How to make it be fully transparent?
[image]

Comment: In case helps anyone - found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28017396/how-can-i-style-the-searchview-when-using-a-toolbar-as-an-action-bar/28018439#28018439), how could I miss it?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the background color when you create your `searchView` like this:

```
SearchView searchView = findViewById(R.id.searchView); 
EditText editText = (EditText)searchView.findViewById(context.getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null));
editText.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Comment: while this may work,I don't like the solution, it is very error-prone - I don't want to know the internals of the SearchView to modify it, this pure styling issue.

Answer (score 0):

so I know some time has passed, but I had similiar problem with different color for toolbar and searchview even if I set the same for both. What helped for me was instead of setting background color for SearchView setting the backgroundTint, so:

instead of `android:background="#BF29D2EB"` use `android:backgroundTint="#BF29D2EB"` for your SearchView