# how to customize searchview edittext?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-custom-view, androidx, searchview

I want to customize my searchview edittext which expanded when I click on searchview icon to be like this image

[image]

And I tried the custom style to do that but I got this result in this image
[image]

The problems:

1. There is a blue vertical bar at the start of the edittext I need to remove it and make it appears only on a search query and after the querytext also I want to change the color of this vertical bar
2. I need to add a white search icon with specific padding of the hint and text query currently the white icon in the result screen disappears on search query

How I got this result?

I define searchViewStyle

```
   <style name="SearchViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
        <item name="searchIcon">@drawable/ic_baseline_dark_search_24</item>
        <item name="closeIcon">@null</item>
        <item name="goIcon">@drawable/ic_baseline_dark_search_24</item>
        <item name="commitIcon">@drawable/ic_baseline_dark_search_24</item>
        <item name="android:editTextColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/red</item>
        <item name="queryBackground">@drawable/radius_drawable</item>
        <item name="searchHintIcon">@drawable/ic_baseline_search_24</item>
        <item name="queryHint">"search_hint"</item>
    </style>
```

I define searchview like this in my fragment layout

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
android:id="@+id/searchView"
style="@style/SearchViewStyle"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

</androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView>
```

I define a custom drawable background for searchview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners
        android:radius="18dp"
        />
    <solid
        android:color="#4F4F4F"
        />
    <padding
        android:left="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:bottom="0dp"
        />
    <size
        android:width="270dp"
        android:height="60dp"
        />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

While I do not clearly understand what your requirements are exactly, I would like to point out one thing though.
For Applying a style to a `SearchView` we have to use the theme attribute, your code seems okay, maybe your changes are not being applied for now I believe. So try using the `android:theme` attribute for your style as follows. The rest of your requirements should easily come by to you with some trial and error I believe. Thanks.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
android:id="@+id/searchView"
android:theme="@style/SearchViewStyle"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
```

Here is how I would recommend you to update your style to get as close as possible to your design.

```xml
<style name="SearchViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
        <item name="searchIcon">@drawable/ic_baseline_dark_search_24</item>
        <item name="queryBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="queryHint">"search_hint"</item>
        <item name="iconifiedByDefault">false</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/radius_drawable</item>
    </style>
```

And you can modify your drawable and get rid of the padding and size since you are using `wrap_content` in your layout

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#4F4F4F" />
    <corners android:radius="18dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: it doesn't work and gives me this result: https://ibb.co/N65bHFM

Comment: Let me try to update my answer. Can you clarify if you have all the required drawable made for the design you need @Amin

Comment: updated the question you can check it again

Comment: I have updated the answer @Amin. You may try again

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom searchview in AppCompat `SearchView` . Copy searchview from this link [searchview.xml](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/appcompat/res/layout/abc_search_view.xml)

Then edit the xml or remove the extra margin from xml.
Add custom `searchview` layout like this:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
                android:id="@+id/search" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                app:layout="@layout/custom_search_view"
                app:iconifiedByDefault="true"
                app:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent"
                app:queryHint="Search"
                app:searchIcon="@drawable/search" />
```